# Custom Post types categories are creating additional page indexes but pointing to the same archive

Tags: custom-post-types

This is a little hard to explain, so here goes.

Have a WordPress site with a Custom Post Type - "Servies". Which has (example) 3 categories.

What is happening, is that the Google are indexing additional pages based on the number of categories there are for the post type.

Example:

https://example.com/services/

https://example.com/services/page/2/

https://example.com/services/page/3/

All of these are pointing to exactly the same page as https://example.com/services/ (therefore duplicating content essentially).

Comment: If the archive pages don't have the exact same content, then it's not duplicate content.. Those paged requests (e.g. `/page/2`) are there because the category posts are not shown all at once on the same page (page #1).

Comment: How many posts of that CPT do you have?

Comment: Yep there's 15 posts. The posts per page was set to 6, so created page/2/ and page/3/ to count the posts. I believe that I have an understanding why this has happened now. It would have been better to use a page template for the archive page (services), then pull the posts from the post types to eliminate the pagination issues there.